# Custom indentation in Clojurescript and Cider for 3rd party macro

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, cider

I use the `async` macro in Clojurescript

```
(:require
 [cljs.test :refer-macros [async deftest is testing run-tests]]
```

and Cider wants to indent it like this

```
(async done
       (go
```

The Cider manual only talks about custom indentation for 1st party macros

https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/indent_spec/
https://cider.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/indentation/

How do I tell Ciderto use `{:style/indent 1}` for a 3rd party macro in Clojurescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be configured in clojure-mode (a dependency of CIDER), documentation is [here](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/tree/5.11.0#indentation-of-macro-forms).

For example, `(put-clojure-indent 'async 1)`.